# Caesar Cipher Java Program can't shift more than 23

Tags: java, caesar-cipher

I'm creating a program to do a **Caesar Cipher**, which shifts the letters in a word one time when I hit enter, and prompts the user to shift again or quit.

It works until I get to **23 shifts**, then it starts using non-letter symbols for some reason, and I'm not sure why this is happening.

Any suggestions? Here is the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cipher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // encrypted text
        String ciphertext;

        // input from keyboard
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        if (args.length > 0) {
            ciphertext = "";
            try {
                Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
                while (inputFile.hasNext())
                    ciphertext += inputFile.nextLine();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println("File not found: " + args[0]);
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.print("Please enter text--> ");
            ciphertext = keyboard.nextLine();
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------------------------

        int distance = 0;  // how far the ciphertext should be shifted
        String next = "";  // user input after viewing
        while (!next.equals("quit")) {
            String plaintext = "";
            distance += 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < ciphertext.length(); i++) {
                char shift = ciphertext.charAt(i);
                if (Character.isLetter(shift)) {
                    shift = (char) (ciphertext.charAt(i) - distance);
                    if (Character.isUpperCase(ciphertext.charAt(i))) {
                        if (shift > '0' && shift < 'A') {
                            shift = (char) (shift + 26);
                            plaintext += shift;
                        } else {
                            plaintext += shift;
                        }
                    }
                    if (Character.isLowerCase(ciphertext.charAt(i))) {
                        if (shift > '0' && shift < 'a' && ciphertext.charAt(i) < 't') {
                            shift = (char) (shift + 26);
                            plaintext += shift;
                        } else {
                            plaintext += shift;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    plaintext += shift;
                }
            }

            System.out.println(ciphertext);

            // At this point, plaintext is the shifted ciphertext.
            System.out.println("distance " + distance);
            System.out.println(plaintext);
            System.out.println("Press enter to see the next option,"
                    + "type 'quit' to quit.");
            next = keyboard.nextLine().trim();
        }
        System.out.println("Final shift distance was " + distance + " places");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: `...plaintext += shift; } else { plaintext += shift; }` — This doesn't make sense. You can put the `plaintext += shift` statement outside the `else`.

Comment: Just so you know - past `'Z'` and `'z'` are a handful of characters that have nothing to do with letters.  You're going to want to skip those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does the shifting in your method work? Well, it exploits the fact that a `char` can, in Java, also be viewed as an `int`, a simple number.

Because of that you can do stuff like this:

```
char c = 'A';                                 // Would print: A
int cAsValue = (int) c;                       // Would print: 65
int nextValue = cAsValue + 1;                 // Would print: 66
char nextValueAsCharacter = (char) nextValue; // Would print: B
```

or even that:

```
int first = (int) 'A';                // Would print: 65
int second = (int) 'D';               // Would print: 68
int third = first + second;           // Would print: 133
char thirdAsCharacter = (char) third; // Would not print anything meaningful
```

---

Okay, now that we know how we can interpret `char` as `int`, let us analyze why `65` represents the character `A` and why `133` is nothing meaningful.

The keyword here is **UTF-16**. Characters in Java are encoded in `UTF-16` and there are tables that list all characters of that encoding with their specific decimal number, like [here](http://asecuritysite.com/coding/asc2).

Here is a relevant excerpt:

[image: UTF-16 table showing characters around 'A']

This answers why `65` represents `A` and why `133` is nothing meaningful.

---

The reason why you experience strange results after **some shifts** is that the alphabet only has a size of **26 symbols**.

I think you would expect that it starts all over again and `a` shifted by `26` is again `a`. But unfortunately your code is not smart enough, it simply takes the current character and adds the shift to it, like that:

```
char current = 'a';
int shift = 26;

int currentAsInt = (int) current;        // Would print: 97
int shifted = currentAsInt + shift;      // Would print: 123
char currentAfterShift = (char) shifted; // Would print: {
```

Compare that to the relevant part in the table:

[image: UTF-16 table showing characters around '{']

So after `z` does not come `a` again but rather `{`.

---

So after the mystery was solved, let's now talk about how to fix it and make your code smarter.

You can simply check the bounds, like "*if it is greater than the value for 'z' or smaller than 'a', then get it back again into the correct range*". We can do so easily by using the **modulo operator** given by `%`. It divides a number by another and returns the remainder of the division.

Here is how we can use it:

```
char current = 'w';
int shift = 100;
int alphabetSize = 26; // Or alternatively ('z' - 'a')

int currentAsInt = (int) current;          // Would print: 119
int shiftInRange = shift % alphabetSize;   // Would print: 22
int shifted = currentAsInt + shiftInRange; // Would print: 141 (nothing meaningful)

// If exceeding the range then begin at 'a' again
int shiftCorrected = shifted;
if (shifted > 'z') {
    shiftCorrected -= alphabetSize; // Would print: 115
}

char currentAfterShift = (char) shiftCorrected; // Would print: s
```

So instead of shifting by `100` we only shift be the relevant part, `22`. Imagine the character going **three rounds** through the whole alphabet because `100 / 26 ~ 3.85`. After those **three rounds** we go the remaining `0.85` rounds which are `22` steps, the **remainder** after dividing `100` by `26`. That is exactly what the `%` operator did for us.

After going that `22` steps we could still exceed the bound, but maximally by one round. We correct that by subtracting the alphabet size. So instead of going `22` steps, we go `22 - 26 = -4` steps which emulates "*going 4 steps to the end of the alphabet, then starting at 'a' again and finally going 18 steps to 's'*".