# Unexpected characters in char array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to understand this particular program but am having trouble understanding what this specific method does.

The method takes the param `String playerShip` which is user entered and must be in the form (letter)(number) where the letters can range from a-g and numbers can range from 1-8, considering the ships will be placed on an 8x8 board. So an example of the string would be "A6", "E2" etc..

also `private char[][] board = new char[8][8];`

and `pShip=0;`

I know that this method will take the user entered string and try to place it onto the 8x8 board but where is the 49 and 65 coming from?

```
  /**

     * Sets a player ship on the board by replacing an 's' into board array 
  * user-defined coordinates, increments playerShips for each ship added
     *
     * @param playerShip coordinates of player ship entered by user
     */

   public void setPlayerShips(String playerShip) {

        board[((int) playerShip.charAt(1)) - 49][((int) playerShip.charAt(0)) - 65] = 's';
        pShip++;
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly why you should not use "magic" numbers when programming

Comment: Check: What does `(char)65` represent?

Comment: Would it be capital A?

Comment: .......yep, and 49?

Comment: You may take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45705128/2411243) where the *magic* with `char`s gets explained.

Comment: okay got it! thanks for your help everyone

Answer (score 2):

These are ASCII codes: 49 is for 1 and 65 is for letter 'A'. The code is computing the difference between ascii value for each number and upper case letter at that step

Answer (score 1):

The programmer writing the code is simply converting a set of ASCII coordinates to integer offsets for use in the array.  Unfortunately, there's nothing in the code that verifies that `playerShip.charAt(1)` or 0 will return valid characters.

The reason that this works is that the ASCII code for a capital A is 0x41 or 65.  Subtracting 65 from a capital letter results in an integer offset.  I leave it to you to work out what 49 is in ASCII.

While at least one comment mentions that the developer chose to use a "magic number", which is almost always unwise, in this case I suspect that he assumed that any developer reading his code would be familiar with this approach to converting characters to integer values.

Answer (score 0):

This method is converting the given (letter-number) string coordinates into the corresponding position in the board matrix and setting it with 's' (which seems to be the defined value that indicates that there is part of a ship in that board position).

As others have mentioned, to map the given characters (the first, a letter character and the second, a number character) to values between 0 and 7 to index the board matrix, the programmer subtracted the ASCII value for the first character of the valid range. From A-H the ASCII characters code go from 65 (A) up to 72 (H) so when you pick a letter in that range and subtract 65 (the integer value of A, you obtain a value in the indexable range of the board matrix (0-7). Same thing applies to the second character that ranges from 1-8 and the ASCII codes for these characters range from 49 (for character 1) to 56 (for character 8) so the programmer subtracted 49 to obtain, once more, a number from 0-7 to index the other dimension of the board matrix.

I suggest you google for "ASCII table" so you can take a look at how printable and nonprintable characters of the ASCII coding are mapped to integer numbers as it widely used in all programming languages and a nice thing to understand some of the inner workings of string coding.